# bootstrap-table filtering table data with input tags

Tags: input, filtering, jquery-select2, bootstrap-table

i am trying to filter a bootstrap table using filter-controler or select2-filter extensions by wenzihixin (listed [here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/))

i am creating editable fields in my table like so:

```
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>
          <td><input data-id="2" data-field="fieldname" value = "bird"></td>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "pig"></td>
          <td><input data-id="4" data-field="fieldname" value = "dog"></td>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>
          <td><input data-id="5" data-field="fieldname" value = "pig"></td>
          <td><input data-id="2" data-field="fieldname" value = "dog"></td>
          <td><input data-id="7" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>              
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>
          <td><input data-id="2" data-field="fieldname" value = "bird"></td>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "pig"></td>
          <td><input data-id="4" data-field="fieldname" value = "dog"></td>
          <td><input data-id="1" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>
          <td><input data-id="5" data-field="fieldname" value = "pig"></td>
          <td><input data-id="2" data-field="fieldname" value = "dog"></td>
          <td><input data-id="7" data-field="fieldname" value = "cat"></td>              
       </tr>
       ...etc...
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

(this is just bogus data by the way, i can't reveal the real data).

i've tried using select2-filter and filter-control to filter results in the tabl, and they both work, but they both end up filtering on ALL my data between the TD tags, so if i were to filter on '1' it would return all rows where that column's data-id = "1".

my question is, how do i limit these (either extension will work fine) to look ONLY at the input tag's value?

Answer (score -1):

One way is to separate the data from the formatting of the input box.  [Look at this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jimkennelly/d6pg90jd/)

Use the format (data-format) parameter to format the input box html.  The format function has parameters (value, row, and index)  field that can be used to create html with classes, hyperlinks, buttons, checkboxes, etc.  Note: I suspect the id field is from your data so I added it to the json data array from one of the [sample codes shown here](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/).

```
function formatInput(value,row,index){
return '<input data-id="' + row.id + '" value="' + value + '">';
}
```

Comment: He's not asking how to show the inputs, but rather how to filter them correctly.